# Disabling of default password generation when using spring-actuator not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am using a third party jar in my application for validation which is using spring security for its business requirements and when I'm trying to use that third party jar, its generating the default password. I can stop the password generation by using

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

But when I've spring boot actuator starter in my application, the exclusion above is not working as expected.
Please let me know if there is any way around for this, I don't want to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and permit all.

UPDATE:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.test.security'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `pom.xml` (or build.gradle)?

Comment: Hi Eugen, Please find the build.gradle where I'm trying to use security and starter together and bypass default password generation with annotation given above.